# How get class description from bytecode?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, analytics, bytecode

**Get description** not load class, I want some library that can read '.class' file and return some object, that hold method names and string parameters for it. Some library that can work as Intellij Idea when it does not load the source it simply list public methods with full path parameters to it. Is such tool avaible for free?

Answer (score 2):

You could create one using byte code engineering libraries like [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).  [Dependency finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html) dumps information about classes into xml. It almost has all the information you want. You may start from its source code.

Sample

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class DemoClassReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassVisitor v= new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {

            @Override
            public void visit(int version, int access, String name,
                              String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
                System.out.println(" class: "+name);
                System.out.println("parent  class: "+superName);
                super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
            }

            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int i, String method, String desc, String signature, String[] strings) {
                System.out.println("method name/block= " + method);
                System.out.println("descriptor   = " + desc);
                System.out.println("signature  = " + signature);
                System.out.println("declared exceptions=" + Arrays.toString(strings));
                return super.visitMethod(i, method, desc, signature, strings);    
            }
        } ;

        InputStream in=String.class.getResourceAsStream("/java/lang/String.class");
        ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(in);
        classReader.accept(v, 0);
    }
}
```

[This library](http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/aspectwerkz/transform/inlining/AsmHelper.html) could help in parsing descriptor string to arguments..

Answer (score 1):

try javassist http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html
Usage example:

```
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    InputStream ins = new FileInputStream("Test.class");
    CtClass cc = cp.makeClass(ins);
    CtField[] fields = cc.getDeclaredFields();
    ...
```

this way we get class description without loading the class